# Pythonic way to group list by key

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list that looks like this:

```
[
  [1, "a", 319],
  [1, "b", 991],
  [2, "Cd", 19],
  [3, "88x", 2891],
  [3, "foo", 11]
]
```

What is the most "pythonic" way of turning this into:

```
[
  [1, [["a", 319], ["b", 991]]],
  [2, [["Cd", 19]]],
  [3, [["88x", 2891], ["foo", 11]]]
]
```

I know how to do it using `for` loops and such, but I'm after a cleaner approach.

Comment: I think you want `groupby`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Comment: A `collections.DefaultDict` might be easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one option assuming the list is sorted by the first element before hand:

```
from itertools import groupby    
[[k, [x[1:] for x in g]] for k, g in groupby(lst, key = lambda x: x[0])]

#[[1, [['a', 319], ['b', 991]]],
# [2, [['Cd', 19]]],
# [3, [['88x', 2891], ['foo', 11]]]]
```

Comment: That works. Sorting the list is possible in my case since it comes from a database SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `collections.defaultdict` if you don't mind a dictionary-like object:

```
>>> l = [
...   [1, "a", 319],
...   [1, "b", 991],
...   [2, "Cd", 19],
...   [3, "88x", 2891],
...   [3, "foo", 11]
... ]
>>> import collections
>>> d = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, *v in l:
...     d[k].append(v)
...
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(d)
{1: [['a', 319], ['b', 991]],
 2: [['Cd', 19]],
 3: [['88x', 2891], ['foo', 11]]}
```